# Xcode 9.1 - Ambigous reference to member filter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, swift4

I already experienced this issue in the past, I fixed it.

But today I just download the new Xcode version 9.1 and my App is not building anymore, I got :

> Ambiguous reference to member 'filter'

I don't know why, this is not the piece of code I was working on. The app is building/compiling fine since weeks.

When I check the Release Note on the [Official Apple Website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html), I don't seem to find any reference to my issue.

So here is the piece of code that was working perfectly 2 hours ago :

```
var severeWeather: Results<SevereWeather>?
var vigiArray = Array<SevereWeather>()
var redCount: Int = 0

severeWeather = realm.objects(SevereWeather.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "department != nil"))
.sorted(byKeyPath: "departmentNumber")

vigiArray = Array(severeWeather!)

redCount = vigiArray.filter { $0.dangerLevels.filter { $0.level.value == 4 }.count > 0 }.count
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: What is the problematic line exactly ?

Comment: The last one. on the .filter

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing your Realm object classes and hence being able to actually test your code, it is quite hard to determine why the compiler cannot decide which `filter` method to use, Realm's or Swift's.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Did you try adding parenthesis:   redCount = vigiArray.filter { ($0.dangerLevels.filter { $0.level.value == 4 }).count > 0 }.count

Comment: Still the ambiguous reference to member filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RealmCollection also has a `filter` method, which is implemented differently. For some reason, Swift compiler doesn't know which one it should refer.

What about this:

```
redCount = vigiArray.filter {
    return $0.dangerLevels.filter(NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "level.value", NSNumber(integerLiteral: 4))).count > 0
}.count
```

Instead of accessing each element in `dangerLevels` yourself, build Predicate and let realm do the job for you.

Replace your nest filter with this and it should be compiling just fine.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. Indeed it was a compiler issue with Swift and Realm filter method.

Comment: Glad i could help :-)