# Ambiguous reference to member '==' with realm filter

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
 do {
        let result = try Realm().objects(Pros.self)
        print(result)
        let filterResult = result.filter({ $0.category.filter({$0.type_cat == ""})})

        print(filterResult)
    }
    catch {

        print(error)

    }
```

and its give me error as "Ambiguous reference to member '=='" 
so what i missing to add

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308773/xcode-9-1-ambigous-reference-to-member-filter

Comment: What structure of Pros & Category objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution and its work perfectly for me

```
do {
            let result = try Realm().objects(Pros.self)
            print(result)
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.type == %@ AND SELF.status == 'valide' AND ANY category.type_sector = %@ AND SELF.status == 'valide'", arrType[(selectedFromType?.row)!], arrTypeSector[(selectedFromSector?.row)!])
            let arrFiltered =  result.filter(predicate)
            print(arrFiltered)


        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), filtering chapter, try to change your request like this:

```
let type = ""
let result = try Realm().objects(Pros.self).filter("category.type_cat ==  %@",type)
```

Comment: it gives me error "Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations"

Comment: @NiravHathi does type_cat is a String?

Comment: Does `category` is an `Array/List` of `Pros`?

Comment: no Pros Contain array of Category and category object contain property type_sector

Comment: [
  {
    "category": [
      {
        "type_sector": ""
      },
      {
        "type_sector": ""
      },
      {
        "type_sector": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": [
      {
        "type_sector": ""
      },
      {
        "type_sector": ""
      },
      {
        "type_sector": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: From previous post I see that `category` contain array of `type_sector`. Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161512/discussion-between-nirav-hathi-and-biloshkurskyi-ss).

Answer (score 0):

`Realm().objects(Pros.self)` will return `Result<Pros>` which kind of Realm Data. Your `filter` function syntax is a function of Swift, doesn't of Realm. You should convert `Result<Pros>` to `[Pros]` before using `filter` like this:

```
let result = Array(try Realm().objects(Pros.self))
let filterResult = result.filter({ $0.category.filter({$0.type_cat == ""})})
```

Or you can using `filter` function build in Realm. Please check realm.io docs.

Comment: @NiravHathi sorry, I have a mistake. Using `Array(realm_result)` instead using `map { $0 }` like original answer. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection<List<Category>>' to closure result type 'Bool'

Comment: @NiravHathi I'm just edited my answer. Using `Array(realm_result)` instead using `map { $0 }`. Please check newest answer.